# Time format in SELECT string

Tags: mysql

I've a question. I want to display all records where "createdat"(column name) is older than 2 weeks.

Normally this is an easy one. The unfortunate problem is, all my records are inserted into the database with the time/date format as followed: `01-01-2020` instead of `2020/01/01`.

I was fiddling around with this one for quite a while. Can you guys please help me?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(createdat, '%d-%m-%Y'), status 
FROM facturen 
WHERE status='Niet voldaan' AND createdat > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 14 DAY)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `createdat`?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? You didn't actually explain a specific issue with the query.

Comment: @barmar its just a VARCHAR

Comment: Could you specify an alias using "as" for your formatted `creatdat` column, and use that for the comparison?

Comment: you'll need to cast it to a datetime then before you can compare it to other dates. But **please** convert that field to a datetime. There's a reason that data type exists - so use it.

Comment: You'll need [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: @ADyson Since i use the dutch date format (Which I put as a VARCHAR into my DB) the string isn't taking the "-14 days" in count. It just shows them all. It doesn't filter.

Comment: U guys, are all awesome! Fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: "Which I put as a VARCHAR into my DB"...that's ultimately the root cause of this issue. So STR_TO_DATE will cover up the problem for now, and I'm glad you've managed to get that working, but ultimately you need to sort out your column's data type. Then you won't need to keep converting (which isn't very efficient) when you want to do comparisons, or sorting, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse the date. You don't need to use `DATE_FORMAT()`, since it's already in that format.

You also should use `<` to get records older than a time, not `>`.

```
SELECT createdat, status
FROM facturen
WHERE status = 'Niet voldaan'
AND STR_TO_DATE(createdat, '%d-%m-%Y') < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar That was it!